# install4j: Show URL action fails without error message when launching GUI mode from command line (Windows and Linux)

Tags: install4j

At the end of the installer we are executing a "Show URL" action to launch our application in the browser. However we see that the browser does not start and the message "An error occurred while starting the browser" is presented to the user (when running without privileges the error message doesn't show up but the browser doesn't start either).

Looking at the log output (using `-Dinstall4j.debug=true -Dinstall4j.logToStderr=true`) there are no exceptions or error messages. In fact it says the action completed successfully:

`[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.finish.ShowURLAction [ID #####]: Execute action
       ...
       Execute action successful after 33607 ms`

NOTE: it's over 33secs because that's the time until I clicked OK on the dialog. The action fails immediately.

Another interesting point is that the action is configured with failure strategy "Ask user whether to quit on failure" however the dialog presented to users only has an "OK" button.

I managed to reproduce all of this on Linux, but some of our users have seen similar behaviour when launching the installer from the command line in Windows.

Does anyone know what the cause of this issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that either `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` or `Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)` return `false` for the JRE that you are using.

As for the action not failing, that is a bug, it will be fixed in 6.1.3. the error message that you see is shown directly be the action. The failure strategy is a generic mechanism for all actions that reacts to whether the action has failed or not.

Comment: Thanks Ingo! Helpful as always!

Comment: I am having the same problem.  However, since my application can launch a browser/URL via Desktop, why can't the uninstaller?  That doesn't seem to make sense.